# TextField with NumberFormatter doesn't allow deleting the entire text

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an issue with a text field in SwiftUI. I'm using NumberFormatter to work with numbers, and everything works fine until I try to delete the entire text.

[image]

As seen in the gif, if we enter text beforehand and try to delete it, it gets truncated up to the last digit.

Is this normal, or is there a way to fix it?

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State var value: Double = 0
    
    private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0.0",
                      value: $value,
                      formatter: numberFormatter)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if isFocused {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            isFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try manually handle the deletion of all text since you're dealing with currency formatting. Use a separate `@State` to track whether the text field is empty and update the value accordingly:

## Edit

Modified the code.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var textValue: String = "" // Add a separate state for the string representation
    @State var value: Double =   0
    
    private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits =   2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits =   2
        formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0.0", text: $textValue, onCommit: {
                // Attempt to convert the string to a double
                if let newValue = numberFormatter.number(from: textValue)?.doubleValue {
                    value = newValue
                } else {
                    value =   0 // Reset to zero if the conversion fails
                }
                // Ensure the textValue is formatted correctly
                textValue = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? "0.00"
            })
            .focused($isFocused)
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if isFocused {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            isFocused = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: textValue) { newValue in
                // Handle the case where the text is cleared
                if newValue.isEmpty {
                    textValue = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:   0)) ?? "0.00"
                    value =   0
                } else {
                    // Update the value with the formatted string
                    if let formattedValue = numberFormatter.number(from: newValue)?.doubleValue {
                        value = formattedValue
                        textValue = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? "0.00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It fixed the issue of an empty string, but the numbers are no longer formatting to two decimal places.

Comment: I modify the code.

Comment: Did you test it because right now user can enter only one character and immediately jumps autofill and even there is problem with delete

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect and without using Double but works or I don't see leaks

```
extension Formatter {
    static let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.currencyCode = "GBP"
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State var value: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0.0",
                      text: $value)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { newValue in
                guard newValue == false else { return }
                guard let doubleValue = Double(value) else { return }
                value = Formatter.numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: doubleValue)) ?? "0.0"
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    if isFocused {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Done") {
                            isFocused = false
                            print(value.toDoubleWithGroupingSeparator)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var toDoubleWithGroupingSeparator: Double? {
        guard let groupingSeparator = Locale.current.groupingSeparator,
              let decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let valueWithSeperator = self.replacingOccurrences(of: groupingSeparator, with: "")
        let valueWithFormattedSeperator = valueWithSeperator.replacingOccurrences(of: decimalSeparator, with: ".")
        
        return Double(valueWithFormattedSeperator)
    }
}
```

So using String and convert this to Double with appropriate grouping/decimal separators.